# python object returned without \n and \t

Tags: python, string, printing

How do I get a python object that is returned to acknowledge /n and /t in a string object that I have created?

I cannot use print and need to have my function assign a returned string object to output, and when I enter the output, it will print out as I want it to be.

Currently my output is this:

```
>>> output = function(input_data)
>>> output
'1\t2\t100\nALL\t100\n2\t1\t20\nALL\t20\nALL\t1\t20\n2\t100\nALL\t120\n'
```

But I want it to be this:

```
>>> output = function(input_data)
>>> output
1   2   100
ALL 100
2   1   20
ALL 20
ALL 1   20
2   100
ALL 120
```

Comment: But why can't you use `print()`?

Comment: As in it needs to follow the way I showed.... so I cannot print(output) in command line. The returned object needs to be able to print out what I need, but the returned object is a string....

Comment: You can use the string you have mentioned anywhere as it is and just use any output method (print or file output) when you want to show the output.

Comment: Now I need to print(output) in command line to make it return the output I need. I don't want to do that. I want the output to be the way I want, just by entering output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact that both of your outputs are the same object, the only difference is that `print(output)` prints the `__str__` method of `output`, which is usually more user-friendly. And typing just `output` prints the `__repr__` method of `output`, which sometimes refers as the "raw" output.

However, there is a work around with this by creating a custom object, subclass of `str`, like this:

```
>>> class cusstr(str):
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
>>> output = function(input_data) # your function...
>>> output = cusstr(output)
>>> output
1   2   100
ALL 100
2   1   20
ALL 20
ALL 1   20
2   100
ALL 120
```

This object overrides the default `__repr__` and make it return it's `__str__` instead.

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thanks!